# Fog OpenSSL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, fog

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using fog. I have been following the fog tutorial found here: http://fog.io/storage/ but I am getting an error. Is there anything obvious that I am missing? My connection object is valid and I can browse directories and existing files. I can create a new text file. But when I try to upload an mp3 I get an ssh error. I am happy to give more information about my setup, I just don't know what is relevant.

when I run this ruby code:

```
connection.directories[1].files.create(key: 'test.mp3', body: File.open("/path/to/test.mp3"), public: true)
```

I get this error:

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION (NameError)
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.45.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:245:in `rescue in block in write_nonblock'
```

I am using ruby 2.0.0-p451

I am on OSX 10.9.5

Here are all the foggy things in my gemfile:

```
fog (1.28.0)
      fog-atmos
      fog-aws (~> 0.0)
      fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
      fog-core (~> 1.27, >= 1.27.3)
      fog-ecloud
      fog-json
      fog-profitbricks
      fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
      fog-riakcs
      fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
      fog-serverlove
      fog-softlayer
      fog-storm_on_demand
      fog-terremark
      fog-vmfusion
      fog-voxel
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    fog-atmos (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-aws (0.1.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-brightbox (0.7.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
    fog-core (1.29.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.38)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
    fog-ecloud (0.0.2)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-json (1.0.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fog-profitbricks (0.0.1)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
      nokogiri
    fog-radosgw (0.0.3)
      fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
    fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-sakuracloud (1.0.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-serverlove (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-softlayer (0.4.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-terremark (0.0.4)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vmfusion (0.0.1)
      fission
      fog-core
    fog-voxel (0.0.2)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xml (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
```

openssl version:

```
openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zd 8 Jan 2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry to hear you are having this issue. We added a check in excon for openssl version because openssl had a release with a bug in it (so we set it up to give a better warning/instruction when you hit that bug to update). We didn't realize that this constant might not be defined in some cases. I've updated the code to skip the check when the constant is undefined and released excon 0.45.3, if you update to that it should avoid this issue.

All that said, I think it is also worth noting that the openssl version you have there is quite outdated (though it maybe is not obviously so, due to backported security fixes). It would probably be a good idea to bump up to something in the 1.0.1 or even 1.0.2 series (probably using a package manager, I use homebrew for this). This might also fix your issue, but regardless is probably a good idea.

Hope that helps!